# I want to create a List with N fields in every node

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using vb.net to do this.

I would like to create a list (so that it can grow dynamically), in which each node has a fixed amount of fields. As follows:

**node 1: name, surname, age.**

**node 2: name, surname, age.**

**...**

**node M: name, surname, age.**

And so on, the number of times you need. That's why I need it to be a list so it can grow indefinitely.

What probe is to create as follows:

`Private tableVirtual As New List (Of String) (11)`

thinking that 11 is the amount of fields I need. (in my example they are only 3).

And try to add like this:

```
tableVirtual.Insert(tabla.Rows(i).Item(9).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(2).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(3).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(4).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(5).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(6).ToString, tabla.Rows(i).Item(7).ToString, "", tabla.Rows(i).Item(8).ToString)
```

But it is not like that or I am not adding correctly.

Comment: Define your own type with those properties and then create a `List` of that type.

Comment: `Private tableVirtual As New List (Of String) (11)`  
The `11` at the end of the list declaration does not define the number of fields that your object has. It actually defines the [capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=netframework-4.8) of your list. The capacity is the number of elements that the list initially expects to store or the total number of elements that will be stored before resizing the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to create an object to refer to each person and their related information.

This is how you would define the object .. I'm assuming you're using a very recent version of Visual Stuio and .net ..

```
Private Class Person
    Public Property FirstNames As String
    Public Property Surname As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class
```

Next you want to create a list that can store objects of this type ..

```
Dim People As New List(Of Person)
```

Finally, the following method, will create a `Person` object and add it to the list of `People`

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim tempPerson As New Person With {.FirstNames = "John", .Surname = "Doe", .Age = 32}
    People.Add(tempPerson)
End Sub
```

Have a search for list tutorials in VB.net :)